# Running and Moving Animation

Tags: core-animation

I have a sequence of images that I would like to animate. I am using the `CAKeyframeAnimation` class to run the animation. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
[keyAnimation setValues:arrayOfImages];  
[keyAnimation setCalculationMode:@"discrete"];  
keyAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;  
keyAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;  
[keyAnimation setRepeatCount:2];  
[keyAnimation setDuration:1.1];  

[myLayer addAnimation:keyAnimation forKey:@"myanimation"];
```

This works fine. However, I need to also move this animation (sequence of images) from one point to another point (on the iphone screen).

I am able to move a static image using the the a `CGMutablePathRef` path reference. But I can't seem to move an animation which utilizes a sequence of images. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what the `CAAnimationGroup` is for? To make two animations on the same layer run at the same time?